# Saving data to JSON file in Python - Issue with appending multiple keys

Tags: python, json, list

I have big data. from the data I want create script. From the big data , I want save data like this :

In pAccountIds1 it will save first 99 ids then go pAccountIds2  next 99 ids as strings and so on. then save it in Parameters directory. Everything ids are saved in pAccountIds1.

This is my expected output:

```
{"Parameters": [
{"pAccountIds1": "886180295749,575789942587,331377892512"},
{"pAccountIds2": "886180295749,575789942587,331377892512"}
]}
```

This is actual behaviour:

```
{
"Parameters": [
    {
        "pAccountIds1": "886180295749,169278231308,888561797329,316900773169,452451531881,263111390741,774531687947,307175455232,160582862483,503763934565,628239060389,732071894519,851207678364,176876819377,852942366732,697301814574,463173411868,813366789735,434423952232,104239629908,850131272446,173873129414,758190182387,917707497382,813660687632,295585687189,946660130177,531405577506,803054876607,150802796093,231981811420,288035531821,187585725025,381266788059,913104880535,109470036896,843076529994,554635727446,384741278002,179697366565,115248717328,834696924337,137711249429,241488429314,574589139538"
    }
]
```

}

this is my sample data:

```
{
    "deployment_map_source": "S3",
    "deployment_map_name": "deployment_maps.yaml",
    "pipeline_definition": {
        "name": "logs",
        "default_providers": {
            "source": {
                "provider": "codecommit",
                "properties": {
                    "account_id": 715151534,
                    "branch": "main"
                }
            },
            "deploy": {
                "provider": "cloudformation",
                "properties": {
                    "action": "replace_on_failure",
                    "stack_name": "subscription"
                }
            }
        },
        "params": {
            "restart_execution_on_update": true
        },
        "targets": [
            {
                "target": 1716335251,
                "properties": {
                    "template_filename": "management.yml",
                    "param_filename": "gen_parameter.json"
                },
                "regions": "us-east-1",
                "path": [
                    82446615151
                ]
            },
            {
                "target": [
                    96342414163,
                    99926626625,
                    362514193959
                ],
                "regions": "us-west-1",
                "path": [
                    96342414163,
                    99926626625,
                    362514193959
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "pipeline_input": {
        "environments": {
            "targets": [
                [
                    [
                        {
                            "id": "715151515151",
                            "name": "logs-pro",
                            "path": 715151515151,
                            "step_name": ""
                        },

                {
                            "id": "286261515151",
                            "name": "logs-dev",
                            "path": 286261515151,
                            "step_name": ""
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    [
                            {
                            "id": "7363514399199001",
                            "name": "logs-pro-dada",
                            "path": 7363514399199001,
                            "step_name": ""
                        },

                {
                            "id": "u2716166633444",
                            "name": "logs-dev",
                            "path": 2716166633444,
                            "step_name": ""
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

here is my script:

```
import json

IGNORE_ACCOUNTID = '981813074321'
OUTPUT_FILE = 'params/gen_parameter.json'

def chunk_list(lst, chunk_size):
    """Helper function to chunk a list into smaller lists."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), chunk_size):
        yield lst[i:i + chunk_size]

def extract_ids_from_targets(targets):
    extracted_ids = []
    for target_group in targets:
        for target_list in target_group:
            for account in target_list:
                if 'id' in account and account['id'] != IGNORE_ACCOUNTID:
                    extracted_ids.append(str(account['id']))
    return extracted_ids

def main():
    with open("display.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        targets = data.get("pipeline_input", {}).get("environments", {}).get("targets", [])
        print(f"Total targets: {sum(map(len, targets))}")

    # Split the targets into groups of 99
    grouped_targets = list(chunk_list(targets, 99))
    print(f"Total groups: {len(grouped_targets)}")

    # Create the final JSON structure
    result = []
    for i, group in enumerate(grouped_targets, start=1):
        extracted_ids = extract_ids_from_targets(group)
        result.append({f"pAccountIds{i}": ','.join(extracted_ids)})

    final_data = {"Parameters": result}
    json_str = json.dumps(final_data, indent=4)

    # Save the result to gen_parameter.json
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') as f:
        f.write(json_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: your first data sample is not a valid JSON

Comment: its just a mock data. I can't share the real data. I just need the logic, why my script saving all data to  pAccountIds1

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I have update the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into your code and found below issue:

- Your data is having two accounts in a list
- In your grouped_targets variable you will have 198 account ids (99 bunchs of 2)
- I updated your code by extracting ids first and then grouping

Below are changes:

```
targets = extract_ids_from_targets(targets)
grouped_targets = list(chunk_list(targets, 99))
```

and

```
for i, group in enumerate(grouped_targets, start=1):
    result[f"pAccountIds{i}"] = ','.join(group)
```

Here is full updated code (see # AFFECTED CODE LINE comment for changes):

```
import json

IGNORE_ACCOUNTID = '981813074321'
OUTPUT_FILE = 'params/gen_parameter.json'

def chunk_list(lst, chunk_size):
    """Helper function to chunk a list into smaller lists."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), chunk_size):
        yield lst[i:i + chunk_size]

def extract_ids_from_targets(targets):
    extracted_ids = []
    for target_group in targets:
        for target_list in target_group:
            for account in target_list:
                if 'id' in account and account['id'] != IGNORE_ACCOUNTID:
                    extracted_ids.append(str(account['id']))
    return extracted_ids

def main():
    with open("display.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        targets = data.get("pipeline_input", {}).get("environments", {}).get("targets", [])
        print(f"Total targets: {len(targets)}")
        print(f"Total targets: {sum(targets, [])}")

    # Split the targets into groups of 99
    targets = extract_ids_from_targets(targets)  # AFFECTED CODE LINE
    grouped_targets = list(chunk_list(targets, 99))
    print(f"Total groups: {len(grouped_targets)}")
    # Create the final JSON structure
    result = {}

    for i, group in enumerate(grouped_targets, start=1):
        result[f"pAccountIds{i}"] = ','.join(group)  # AFFECTED CODE LINE

    final_data = {"Parameters": result}
    json_str = json.dumps(final_data, indent=4)
    ##print(json_str)

    # Save the result to gen_parameter.json
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') as f:
        f.write(json_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```